# Change rails route to params in path

Tags: ruby-on-rails, parameters, routes

Google bot wants to open my Ajax address like:
http://ots.wlasowy.ru/ru?_escaped_fragment_=/ru/pages/service
I have a record like `match 'pages/service',  :to => 'pages#service'` in `routes.rb`.

What else I need to add to `routes.rb`?

My routes.rb:

```
scope "(:locale)", :locale => /en|ru/ do

match '/pages/news' => 'pages#news'
match '/articles/page/:page',  :to => 'pages#news'
match '/pages/home' => 'pages#home'

resources :pages
resources :articles
resources :vacancies

mount Ckeditor::Engine => '/ckeditor'

mount RailsAdmin::Engine => '/admin', :as => 'rails_admin'

devise_for :users

devise_scope :user do
  get "sign_in", :to => "devise/sessions#new"
end

end
```

Answer (score 0):

Add your route.rb, view files. You have some bugs in your code.